# Date issue with Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a `varchar` column which contains date in following format

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

I need to convert the column's datatype to `DATE`. I'm using the following query

```
alter table [tblDocumentRevision]
alter column [RevisionDate] date  null
```

but I get an error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I'm sure that all the values are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. So why is it giving me the error?

Then I added a new column and tried

```
UPDATE [tblDocumentRevision]
SET NewDate = convert(date,[RevisionDate],103)
WHERE ISDATE([RevisionDate]) = 1
```

The check for `ISDATE() = 1` should filter out those entries that cannot be converted to a `DATE`.

Then `NewDate` column has only the values where month and date are both less than or equal to 12 others are null. So I'm clearly seeing a issue with the `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Google to find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx). Try setting the format being running `ALTER COLUMN`.

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTest
(
  MyCol VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #tmpTest(MyCol)
  VALUES('31/12/99');

ALTER TABLE #tmpTest ALTER COLUMN MyCol DATE;
```

Yields:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Whereas:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTest
(
  MyCol VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #tmpTest(MyCol)
  VALUES('31/12/99');

SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

ALTER TABLE #tmpTest ALTER COLUMN MyCol DATE;
```

Yields:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: `SET DATEFORMAT` is a session option not a column property.

Comment: Yes, so set it for your session and then within your session alter the column.

Comment: Ah OK. Misunderstood your suggestion. +1. You might want to change `being` to `before` in your answer so it is clearer what you mean.

Comment: Maybe hold off on the +/- until we see whether it actually works ("This answer should be a comment etc"). I just applied some Google-fu and read the SQL Server documentation.

Comment: +1 Anyway. You can delete it if it doesn't work and because of my previous downvote I won't be able to upvote it later without doing an edit. :-)

Comment: thanx for the reply.you'r solution almost worked.i have successfully converted the column data type to DATE but now the values are in the following format '2008-05-20' which were previously '20/05/2008'.i need the dd/mm/yyyy format.it's a great help if u can give me a suggestion

Comment: That's how SQL Server represents dates. `CONVERT` to a character type with an explicit format specifier if you want a particular string representation.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above, I should have said "that's how SQL Server Management Studio represents dates". SQL Server represents dates as 8 byte binary values...

Answer (score 0):

By default, the date format depends on the locale of the server. Therefore you cannot rely on it using `DD/MM/YYYY` format when not explicitly defining this.

Your approach of adding a new column and use CONVERT with the correct style specifier should work, but you cannot check the dates with the ISDATE function because the function will not know about the custom style to use for parsing the date, unless you change the format expicitly as shown by todda.speot.is.

```
UPDATE [tblDocumentRevision] SET NewDate = convert(date,[RevisionDate],103)
```

Comment: It depends on the language of the login so only indirectly the locale of the server.

Comment: @MartinSmith, true, but unless you configure the login to a specific format with `sp_configure` it will use the server locale. See also [kb173907](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907).